# Can you use Dyrrn’s Tentacle Whip to make a melee spell attack

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, weapons, attack

Dyrrn’s Tentacle Whip is from Eberron: Rising from the Last War , pg. 276

The main question is does the tentacle count as a appendage of the player for the purposes of making a melee spell attack.

Comment: Yes for 5th edition, but for my group if there is precedence from earlier editions we usually go with that if there's nothing directly contradicting it in the 5th edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Dyrrn's Tentacle Whip is a whip, which is a melee weapon.

The Whip appears in the Martial Melee Weapons table of the PHB. Dyrnn's tentacle whip says:

> Weapon (whip), very rare (requires attunement)

So Dyrnn's Tentacle Whip is a melee weapon. When attacking with a melee weapon, *you make a melee weapon attack*, not a melee spell attack.

#### The Tentacle Whip does not extend your reach for melee spell attacks.

The Reach property of weapons says:

> This weapon adds 5 feet to your reach when you attack with it

If you are casting a spell that calls for a melee spell attack, you are not attacking with Dyrnn's Tentacle Whip so the Reach property of the weapon does not apply.

Of course, a DM could rule that it does count, and from a flavor perspective this seems reasonable, *but that would make this magic item extremely powerful*, far more powerful than it is otherwise.

Comment: Does it count as a part of the player due to the symbiotic nature to increase the melee touch range?

Comment: It may be worth noting that *tentacle whips* had this “deliver touch spell” feature in their original incarnation in _Eberron Campaign Setting_ for 3.5e—but even there, it was a separate, explicit feature of the item, which may make the lack thereof in the 5e version a “conspicuous absence” that lends weight to the idea that we shouldn’t be reading it into the item.